# MongoKitten : Sorting by a generated field

Tags: swift, mongodb, mongokitten

I am trying to create the following mongo statement in MongoKitten which is a swift framework.

```
db.pages.find( {$and: [{$text: {$search: "ebay"}} , {"lang" : "en"} ] }, {score: {$meta: "textScore"}}).sort({score:{$meta:"textScore"}})
```

In swift I have the following however I cant get it to sort by the generated field **Score**

```
let query: Query = [
            "$text": ["$search": "ebay" ],
            "lang" : ["$eq": "en"],
        ]

let projection: Projection = [
             "_id": .excluded,
            "url": "url",
            "$score": ["$meta" : "textScore"]
        ]

let sort : Sort = [
            "score": .descending
        ]

        let matchingEntities: CollectionSlice<Document> = try pages.find(query, sortedBy: sort, projecting: projection)
```

Anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a custom `SortOrder`

```
let query: Query = [
            "$text": ["$search": "ebay" ],
            "lang" : ["$eq": "en"]
]
let projection: Projection = [
            "_id": .excluded,
            "url": "url",
            "score": ["$meta" : "textScore"]
]
let sort : Sort = [
            "score": .custom(["$meta" : "textScore"])
]
let matchingEntities: CollectionSlice<Document> = try pages.find(query, sortedBy: sort, projecting: projection)
```